# How can I parse a DICOM file using plain C or C++ file read methods?

Tags: c++, dicom

I am NOT looking for a pre-existing library to read DICOM files. I am looking for some sample code that reads a DICOM file and parses it. No bells and whistles. I need to write the code from scratch. I understand that there are many awesome libraries available, but I need to read the DICOM file manually using old-fashioned C or C++ file read methods. Don't waste your time suggesting libraries. Nothing against libraries! I just need to do this manually.

Specifically, I need to know how to access the values from a DICOM file (most importantly: the pixel values). It would help to know the data types, sizes, and formatting (which I know can vary a lot in DICOM).

Thanks!
-j

Comment: Search the web for "DICOM file format".  You could also search the web for "DICOM file specification".

Comment: Reading a DICOM file is the easy part, interpreting the DataSet is the hard part, hence the multiples suggestions to re-use an existing library.

Comment: Is there a specific, limited set of compression and pixels formats that you want to support instead of trying to support the whole standard? Do you have a representative sample image? I've written my own DICOM viewer and I support much of the standard; it's not a trivial task.

Comment: Hi BitBank: I could potentially hire someone to do this. Let me know.

Answer (score 3):

My inclination is to say "don't do this" but you've indicated that you have your own reasons for wanting to write your own parser - who am I to argue! The "data types,sizes and formatting" of a DICOM file is described in Part 5 (Data Structures and Encoding) and Part 6 (Data Dictionary) of the DICOM Standard. Both Parts are freely available online in a variety of formats at http://www.dclunie.com/dicom-status/status.html#BaseStandard2015a.

The image's pixel data is stored in the attribute with tag (7fe0,0010). The pixel data will be a string of bytes if the image is not compressed. Otherwise the Pixel Data attribute will be a Sequence attribute, and the second sequence item will contain the encapsulated compressed pixel data.

EDIT: there is also some helpful high level information in this answer to a similar question ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/213987/1220389

EDIT 2: The "2014b" release of the DICOM Standard included support for the  "Parametric Map Storage IOD". A "Parametric Map" object is a derived image, much like an acquired image object that we're familiar with, but that the pixel values of a Parametric Map have intrinsic quantitative meaning. As part of the changes introduced to support Parametric Maps the DICOM Standard has introduced the Floating Point Image Pixel module and the Double Floating Point Image Pixel module which include the Float Pixel Data (7fe0,0008) and the Double Float Pixel Data (7fe0,0009) attributes, respectively. That is, the pixel data of an image may now be conveyed in the usual Pixel Data (7fe0,0010) attribute for acquired and most derived images, or in Float Pixel Data (7fe0,0008) or Double Float Pixel Data (7fe0,0009) for Parametric Maps. More information on the changes introduced into the DICOM Standard to support the Parametric Maps Storage IOD are available in [Supp 172 Parametric Map Storage](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/final/sup172_ft2.pdf).

Comment: Why do you think it is a bad idea? For me it is always a good idea to understand the basics. I wrote my own parser too and it helps me much to understand the usage of DICOM and it's features and possibilities.

Comment: The standard recently allowed floating point image data, Pixel Data is no longer located in the famous (7FE0,0010) attribute, so you may need to clarify your answer.

Comment: Claus, if you wrote a DICOM parser then you know that the DICOM standard is large and complicated, and provides for many different object representations. It's one thing to write a parser that kinda-sorta works on this particular subset of images (and perhaps this is exactly what OP had intended) but it's something else to be able to parse all of the Transfer Syntax variants including for example, Deflated, Implicit VR, Big Endian. And as @malat explicitly pointed out above, parsing is the (relatively) easy part of the process, interpretation of the attributes is much more involved.

Comment: But you have a point Claus, and perhaps I shouldn't have been so hasty to discourage OP without knowing what his particular use case is. However to me it just seems kind of silly to ignore the effort, experience and expertise that has already gone into creating some of the high quality readily-available libraries.

Comment: Thanks! Programmers often face the dilemma of choosing between writing something from scratch vs. using a library. When choosing a library one must make sure to choose an appropriate one that doesn't come with too much set up and learning. A bad library choice can end up wasting more time than it would take to write something from scratch. In my case, I do not have a general-purpose goal, and I have a few specific files to read. This is the reason for my initial request. I am still open to using an existing library - but ONLY if it is well-designed, simple, and is based on standard C++.